# problema con JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema un JavaScript que permite no recargar la pagina y que la coloqué en un Div, resulta que la primera vez esta todo bien, pero existe un boton que hace devuelva "atras", funciona todo normal, pero me he fijado que cada que calculo algo que llama a ese JS, se autoincrementa los procesos haciendo que se ponga lenta y se recargue cada que recibe el estado 200.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Existe alguna manera que no se autoincremente, y que cuando de en el boton de "atras", vuelva a 0 el llamado POST y solo ejecute una sola vez?

Muchas gracias.

**Editado**

El Html del Form es el siguiente: "encargado de que reciba los datos del usuario"

```html
<form id="formulario" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<!-- Aquí los campos necesarios que se enviarán por POST mediante JS, Ajax -->

<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-         primary">Calcular</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

Este el script de JS que estoy utilizando, su función es traer datos de un Formulario HTML, y llevarlos a una clase y metodo. "**calcularbalance/calcular**"

```js
    $(document).on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let $target = $(e.currentTarget);
        let url = 'calcularbalance/calcular';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#objeto').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Adicional utilizo un JS que hace que no recargue la pagina, sino que lo coloque en un div, es como especie de "iframe" de html.

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $('body').on('click','a', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        var destinationLocation = $target.attr('href');
        if (destinationLocation !== '#') {
            $('#objeto').load(
                destinationLocation
            );
        }
    });
});
```

El Div siempre va a ser esté y siempre se va a trabajar en él.

```html
<div class="col-9" style="background-color:#FFFF;" id="objeto"></div>
```

Comment: Y ¿cómo podemos ayudarte? Necesitamos el código del JS así como el HTML para ver el `div` y el botón y como los usas.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, pido disculpas por no saberme explicar y añadir el codigo faltate, lo acabé de hacer. En si todo funciona y cumplé con su trabajo, pero siempre el JS cada vez que lo se llama, se va autoincrementando y lo unico es F5 para que eso no suceda.

Answer (score 0):

Esto debería ir en un comentario, pero todavía no tengo la reputación para comentar.

No es necesario tener el JS que evita que se recargue la página, ya que el formulario lo estás enviando por AJAX y por ende, la respuesta se recibirá por AJAX y éste se encargará de suministrar los datos en el div que quieras sin tener que recargar la página.

Intenta eliminar el JS que evita que se recargue la página, haber si eso resuelve la pregunta.

Como nota: yo supongo que ese JS (el de evitar que se recargue la página) no tiene otra función más que esa.

No puedo ayudar más ya que no pones completo el código ni dices exactamente cuales son las funciones de cada cosa. Por ejemplo en el JS (el de evitar que se recargue la página) veo que tienes el de prevenir de ir a los enlaces y en su lugar cargar el contenido html en el mismo div destinado a recibir la respuesta del AJAX.

Saludos